# Require forward-dns not working as expected

Tags: apache, security, dns, dynamic-ip, mod-authz-host

Quick explanation:

- Home hobby server
- Some public services, some I'd like to restrict to internal only
- Since I discovered reverse proxies () I've been migrating everything behind subdomains of my domain, via Apache
- I then discovered that I could no longer simply use `Require local` as before, since Apache always sees the public IP address of the client
- `Require forward-dns` appears to be the solution I want, however it's not giving the expected result
- I'm on a dynamic IP, but the results seem like they should be broadly correct. I just want to understand why this isn't working

Example `.htaccess` on the server (as an initial test):

> Require forward-dns mydomain.biz

Example public IP test from within my home network:

`$ host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`

> ...
>   myip.opendns.com has address a.b.c.d
>   ...

Lookup the domain name:

`$ host mydomain.biz`

> mydomain.biz has address a.b.c.d
>
> mydomain.biz mail is handled by 10 mydomain.biz

However, upon accessing the site from the local network:

> [Thu Aug 09 12:59:35.478812 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 18478:tid
>   139675020785408] [client a.b.c.d:45860] AH01630: client denied by
>   server configuration: /var/www/blah/blah/

So even though `authz_core` receives the expected IP, its forward-dns server *does not* return that IP. So why is this? Am I doing something obviously wrong? Could the mail server be interfering with the result?

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you remove `Require ..` directive, is site accessible?

Comment: Yes indeed. It's only the require that's the problem. I also turned on debug logging, but the output doesn't show exactly how the forward dns verifies, unfortunately

Comment: make sure that hostname used in `Require forward-dns`, when tested from apache machine (for example try piniging the name and see what address is it trying to reach) resolves to a.b.c.d

Comment: Aha! Great suggestion! ping on the machine returns the local IP, so that's surely the source of the problem. Probably just need to edit the hosts file. many thanks!

Comment: I solved this problem by adding the following section to my .conf file:
`<Location />       Require forward-dns mydomain.com    </Location>`