# htaccess: I cannot allow access from a specific domain instead of IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I want to allow the connection from my *LAN* and in the case, that the external ip matches my ip (for when I use my domain to connect internal to my http server via browser)

I found this:

`Require forward-dns bla.example.org`

but I get an 403 Forbidden :/

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.254.1/24
Require forward-dns mydomain.de
```

Thank you :C

Comment: Check what https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765242/require-forward-dns-not-working-as-expected#comment90498735_51765242 suggests first of all maybe.

Comment: Thank you, i did that and everything resolves to the public IP-Address, so it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I have worked out:
I use a scipt to enter the IP address in the hosts file.

Follow the instructions from:
https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/apache-auth-ddns/

After that it works with the following command in .htaccess

`Allow from yourDomain.de`

Its not the best answer, but it will work.